# Design an Android Service like Watchdog For collecting logs from remote devices and upload it to server

Tags: android, android-ndk, watchdog, android-service-binding, bug-reporting

I want to create a bug reporting service in android which collects logs of crashes, ANRs and similar events. It should collect logs for Apps/JAVA Services/Native Services.

I'm not sure which direction I should move forward, have checked out some logging repos but they're just "Logging Repos" and do not provide any info on how logs can be collected system wide and from any app in my device.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

I checked out some logging repos like - RxLogs by umair13adil and Android-Error-Reporter by tomquist but not sure how to leverage these and similar repos for my use case, also want to be sure of any restrictions that would hinder my objectives.